# Java - plotting sine waves

Tags: java, waveform, trigonometry

I am using the following code to generate a sine wave: 
[image: SineWave]

The speed of this animation is slow-fast-slow.
Code:

```
public static final double SINE_TO_180 = 114.58865012930961, TIMES = 180, SINE_OF_90 = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(90));

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    float velc = 200;
    float angle = 45;
    float resistance = 0f;
    double multiple = (velc * 2.5 / SINE_TO_180);
    int offset = 0;
    double y = 0;
    double x = 0;
    double h = 0;
    double cos = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle));
    double sin = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle));
    for(int i = offset; i < TIMES + 1 + offset; i ++){
        y += ((Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i * 2)))) * multiple * sin;
        if(y >= h)
            h = y;
        x += Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i)) * multiple * ((1 - resistance) * 1.5) * Math.abs(cos);
//          x += multiple * cos;
//          if(i + offset < TIMES / 2){
//              x += Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i)) * multiple * ((1 - resistance) * 1.5);
//          }else{
//              x += Math.sin(Math.toRadians(TIMES / 2)) * multiple * (1 - resistance);
//          }
    }
    y = Math.round(y);
    //do round x?
    x = Math.round(x);
    System.out.println("X: " + x);
    JFrame frm = new JFrame("Projectile!");
    frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    BufferedImage b = new BufferedImage((int)x + 1, (int)h + 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics g = b.getGraphics();
    y = 0;
    x = 0;

    JLabel l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(b));
    frm.add(l);
    frm.pack();
    frm.setVisible(true);

    for(int i = offset; i < TIMES + 1 + offset; i ++){
        y += ((Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i * 2)))) * multiple * sin;

        x += Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i)) * multiple * ((1 - resistance) * 1.5) * Math.abs(cos);
 //         x += multiple * cos;
//          if(i + offset < TIMES / 2){
//              x += Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i)) * multiple * ((1 - resistance) * 1.5);
//          }else{
//              x += Math.sin(Math.toRadians(TIMES / 2)) * multiple * (1 - resistance);
//          }
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawLine((int)x, (int)(h - y), (int)x, (int)(h - y));
        l.setIcon(new ImageIcon(b));
        frm.repaint();
        Thread.sleep((int)(1000.0 / 24.0));
    }
    ImageIO.write(b, "png", new File("C:\\proj.png"));
}
```

Now I would like to change the sine animation to fast-slow-fast where it is slow at its peak so I tried the following result and got this: 
[image: SineWave2] 
 I would expect it to be the same just the animation speed different. Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    float velc = 200;
    float angle = 45;
    float resistance = 0f;
    double multiple = (velc * 2.5 / SINE_TO_180);
    int offset = 0;
    double y = 0;
    double x = 0;
    double h = 0;
    double cos = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle));
    double sin = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle));
    for(int i = offset; i < TIMES + 1 + offset; i ++){
        y += (1 - Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i * 2))) * multiple * sin;
        if(y >= h)
            h = y;
//          x += Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i)) * multiple * ((1 - resistance) * 1.5) * Math.abs(cos);
        x += 2;
        //          x += multiple * cos;
//          if(i + offset < TIMES / 2){
//              x += Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i)) * multiple * ((1 - resistance) * 1.5);
//          }else{
//              x += Math.sin(Math.toRadians(TIMES / 2)) * multiple * (1 - resistance);
//          }
    }
    y = Math.round(y);
    //do round x?
    x = Math.round(x);
    System.out.println("X: " + x);
    JFrame frm = new JFrame("Projectile!");
    frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    BufferedImage b = new BufferedImage((int)x + 1, (int)h + 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics g = b.getGraphics();
    y = 0;
    x = 0;

    JLabel l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(b));
    frm.add(l);
    frm.pack();
    frm.setVisible(true);

    for(int i = offset; i < TIMES + 1 + offset; i ++){
        y += (1 - Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i * 2))) * multiple * sin;
        x += 2;
//          x += Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i)) * multiple * ((1 - resistance) * 1.5) * Math.abs(cos);
//          x += multiple * cos;
//          if(i + offset < TIMES / 2){
//              x += Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i)) * multiple * ((1 - resistance) * 1.5);
//          }else{
//              x += Math.sin(Math.toRadians(TIMES / 2)) * multiple * (1 - resistance);
//          }
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawLine((int)x, (int)(h - y), (int)x, (int)(h - y));
        l.setIcon(new ImageIcon(b));
        frm.repaint();
        Thread.sleep((int)(1000.0 / 24.0));
    }
    ImageIO.write(b, "png", new File("C:\\proj2.png"));
}
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong because I expect the result to be the same as the first just different animation speeds?

Comment: can you explain what you mean by 'animation speed' ?  is it the time between two points that are drawn?  if yes, then i must correct you: the time to draw a point is always the same time! but the distance between two points is changing! as shown in example 2 you always 'walk' two pixels to forward, whereas in example 1 you move differently amount of pixels forward (very little in the beginning, more in the middle and again very little in the end)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to have a smooth animation i would seperate the data and the animation;

first create your data - it is a (mathematical) function [meaning f(x)->y], so you can simply use an array for data

```
private int endOfX = 100; //adjust as you wish
private int[] data;
public void calculateData(){
    data = new int[amendOfX ountPixels];
    for(int x = 0; x < endOfX ; x++){
        y = x*x; //this is an example, use your mathematical function here
    }
}
```

so - now you can easily use this data to provide a smooth animation

```
public class AnimationOfFunction(){
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new AnimationOfFunktion().createAndShowGui(); //as from java tutorials
    }

    private BufferedImage img;
    private Graphics gr;
    private void createAndShowGui(){
        calculateData(); first of all we create the data!
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();//then create your frame here
        JPanel panel = createContent(); //create your drawing panel here
        frame.add(panel);//adding drawing panel
        frame.pack(); //setting the proper size of frame
        frame.setVisible(true); //show frame          
        startAnimation(panel); //this is important - after showing the frame you start your animation here!
    }
}
```

so - this would be the start of you application, what to do now? first create a proper drawing panel:

```
private JPanel createContent(){
    //create a anonym class
    @surpress serial
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(){

        @override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics gr){
            super.paintComponent(gr);
            gr.drawImage(img, 0,0, null);
        }

    } 
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight() ));
    return panel;
}
```

and most important - you have to start the animation:

```
private void startAnimation(final JPanel panel){
    //create a anonym class
    Runnable r = new Runnable(){
        private int py = 0; //previous values
        private int py = 0; //previous values
        @overrdie
        public void run(){
            for(int x = 0; x < endOfX ; x++){
                int y = data[x];
                //now we have x and y, so you can plot your function;
                gr.drawLine(px, py, x,y); //you can scale here
                int sleeptime = calculateSleepTime(px,py, x,y);
                Thread.sleep(sleeptime);

                //set the previouse values;
                px = x;
                py = y;

                //important - repaint your panel to create an 'animation'
                panel.repaint();

            }
        }
    }

    //having that runnable we must start that runnable within an thread
    Thread thread = new Thread(r);
    thread.setDaemon(true);
    thread.start();
}
```

so whats left to do? we must calculate the sleep time: if the distance between two points is 'big' we sleep longer, if the distance is short, we sleep less...

```
public int calculateSleeptime(int px, int py, int x, int y){
    int distance = (y-py)*(y-py)+(x-px)*(x-px);
    distance = (int)(Math.sqrt(distance);
    int sleepTime = distance*100; //play with this value!
    return sleeptime;
}
```

I have written that code all out of my head, i didn't have any IDE to check if it contains any spelling errors or compiling errors, please do that for yourself, as well as i didn't initiate the BufferedImage img ang Graphics gr. but obvious you can do that already!

Comment: I followed your code but it ended out the same! It had a weird line like my second example.

Comment: maybe you could describe what graph you are expecting? my code sample can be easily adjust so it plots your function....   tell me please how it should look like (maybe adding a picture?)